# A better expectation operator which plays nicely with undersetting?

Tags: math-operators

I would like to define an expectation operator that acts like `\iint` in the following sense: I want it to behave nicely with limits in that I would like it to default to place text to the right, but with `\limits`, place it under. Here's an example of ways that don't work and do work.

[image]

The last line is my desired result, but is done manually. How do I do this automatically?

The code producing this is below.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\bf E}
\DeclareMathOperator{\EE}{\bf E}
\newcommand{\EEE}{\mathop{{\bf E}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\iint_{R} f(x, y)\, dx dy \qquad \mbox{versus} \qquad \iint\limits_{R} f(x, y) \, dx dy
\]
\[
\E_{R} f(X, Y) \qquad \mbox{versus} \qquad \E\limits_{R} f(X, Y)
\]
\[
\EE_{R} f(X, Y) \qquad \mbox{versus} \qquad \EE\limits_{R} f(X, Y)
\]
\[
\EEE_{R} f(X, Y) \qquad \mbox{versus} \qquad \EEE\limits_{R} f(X, Y)
\]
desired result (but less ad-hoc)
\[
\mathbf{E}_{R} f(X, Y) \qquad \mbox{versus} \qquad \underset{R}{\mathbf{E}}~f(X, Y)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\bf` has been deprecated for 25 years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the model of `\int` for this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname*{\mathbf{E}}\ilimits@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\iint_{R} f(x, y)\, dx \, dy \qquad \text{versus} \qquad \iint\limits_{R} f(x, y) \, dx \, dy
\]
\[
\E_{R} f(X, Y) \qquad \text{versus} \qquad \E\limits_{R} f(X, Y)
\]

\end{document}
```

Using `\ilimits@` will make the command obey the `intlimits` option just like `\int`.

Use `\nolimits` instead of `\ilimits@` if you don't want that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll take your comment about `\bf` (and your more subtle hint about `\text` versus `\mbox`) under advisement. Have you thought about compiling some of these common TeX deprecations/crimes against LaTeX?

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, `\DeclareMathOperator` will not react to `\limits`.  However, `\DeclareMathOperator*` *will* react to `\nolimits`.  So this should give you the result you are lookiing for:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{{}\bf E}

\[
\E\nolimits_{R} f(X, Y) \qquad \mbox{versus} \qquad \E_{R} f(X, Y)
\]
```

For technical reasons, I'm not able to show output. (Since retiring from AMS, I have lost access to all my previous resources, and haven't yet rebuilt a working system.)

The presence of the `{}` in the definition is intended to counteract the default positioning of a single character as an operator to be vertically centered on the math axis.  This is the default (specified in Appendix G of the TeXbook) so that operators such as `\sum`, `\int`, etc., are properly positioned.

The inability of the unstarred `\DeclareMathOperator` to react to `\limits` seems unreasonable, so I will make a request for it to be implemented in a future release of `amsopn`.

**Update.**  I have been urged to check the documentation in `amsopn.dtx`, and there I find that `\limits` has been purposely inhibited, as pointed out by @egreg.  I therefore withdraw the suggestion that it be made available.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator` has been defined *purposely* not to obey to `\limits` and I fully agree with the decision. It is for operators which never take limits; those which do are defined with `\DeclareMathOperator*`.

Comment: @egreg -- I stand corrected.  The restriction on `\limits` is documented in `amsopn.dtx`, which I didn't check before.  I retract the suggestion that it should be made available.

Answer (score 3):

Your  first operator works the other way:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbf E}
\DeclareMathOperator{\EE}{\mathbf E}
\newcommand{\EEE}{\mathop{{\mathbf E}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\iint_{R} f(x, y)\, dx dy \qquad \mbox{versus} \qquad \iint\limits_{R} f(x, y) \, dx dy
\]
\[
\E_{R} f(X, Y) \qquad \mbox{versus} \qquad \E\nolimits_{R} f(X, Y)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Makes sense. I selected the other one, because the default behavior I'd like to be what yours requires `\nolimits` for. Useful information, nonetheless, however.

Comment: The ‘normal way’ doesn't seem to work for a reason I can't explain. Maybe some guru will have an explanation.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator{\a}{b}` basically defines `\a` as `\mathop{\operator@font{b}}\nolimits@`, where `\nolimits@` is an ams macro written so that `\nolimits@\limits` expands to `\nolimits`, so it stops you changing the limits behaviour. I don't know why amsmath is designed like this. If you write `\EE\relax\limits_R` with the example above it will look OK, so an alternative would be `\DeclareMathOperater{\E}{\mathbf{E}} \newcommand\EE{\E\relax}`, and this might be better in another instance if the operator font effects were desired.

Comment: @AlexWatson: The reason why the `amsmath` (actually, the `amsopn`) package is designed like that is, according to the comments in `amsopn.dtx`, to prevent an explicit “`\limits` typed by the user from having any effect. This is used for operatornames whose standard usage is never to have limits”.  In other words, people at the AMS were concerned that somebody could smuggle something like `\sin\limits^2 x + \cos\limits^2 x = 1` into a submitted manuscript and have such an eyesore make it in print on some of the journals they publish.  But `\EE\limits\limits` isn’t catched…

Comment: Perhaps @barbarabeeton can cast more light on the rationale that lay behind the choice of having `\DeclareMathOperator` behave the way it does.

Comment: @GuM The definition of `\DeclareMathOperator` (without `*`) does a check for a following `\limits` and essentially discards it, forcefully adding `\nolimits` instead; it could go on forever looking for `\limits`: `\def\nolimits@{\@ifnextchar\limits{\expandafter\nolimits@\@gobble}{\nolimits}}` would do. There would be ways to defeat this, though: `\EE\displaylimits\limits`, for instance. The developer wanted to catch obvious errors by inexperienced users.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for your reply; but the TeXnical side of the matter is perfectly clear to me.  What I’m curious about is the *motivation* for which that behavior was built into `\operatorname` (and `\DeclareMathOperator`).  An ideal answer should not rely on conjectures, best of all would be to quote some (legacy?) documentation.

Comment: @GuM I guess the developers wanted to avoid users doing silly things such as `\sin\limits^2`. Possibly in reaction to some code they saw in submitted papers.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `\nolimits` after the definition of the operator:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\EE{\mathop{{}\mathbf{E}}\nolimits}

\begin{document}

\[ \EE_R F \text{ versus } \EE\limits_R F \]

\end{document}
```

You can find a hint to this in a double-dangerous-curve part of chapter 17 in the TeXBook: 'If you say `\nolimits\limits` (presumably because some macro like `\int` specifies `\nolimits`, but you do want them), the last word takes precedence.'

The default behaviour of operators is `\displaylimits`, as you found.

(Following egreg's comment: the `{}\mathbf{E}` ensures the correct the vertical alignment.)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: This vertically moves the E; check against `\newcommand{\fixedEE}{\mathop{{}\mathbf{E}}\nolimits}`

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I have updated the answer.